# What gas turbines have the following configuration?

Tags: turbofan, engine-design, turbine, compressor

Is there any jet engines--with published data on the dimension of the turbines and compressors--that are of the configuration of 2 Low Pressure compressor, 8 High Pressure compressor, 2 High Pressure turbine, 5 Low Pressure Turbine? Thank you very much!

Comment: Do the numbers refer to the number of stages?

Comment: yes, it does. Do you know any?

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't find any that exactly match. The closest ones I found where

PW1000G-56 : 2-8 and 2-3

PD-14 : 3-8 and 2-6

What is the reason your looking for such specific architecture?